# Unable to Redirect the HTML Page via JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on making a simple decide your own destiny style game using just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I began to write up a function to detect what choice, out of a selection of radio buttons, they wanted to select, but then when I wrote up the function to make the page (HTML) change using JavaScript's "location.replace", I kept getting the same alert regardless of what button was selected.

```html
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A1')" value="A1" checked> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A2')" value="A2"> Proin volutpat eros fringilla felis euismod laoreet a eu velit. <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A3')" value="A3"> Mauris orci mi, luctus in leo eget, facilisis imperdiet lacus. <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick=choiceA()> Choose </button>
    </form>
```

```
var selectedButton = 'A1';
function getRadioValue(param){
    selectedButton = param;
    console.log(selectedButton);
}

function choiceA(){
  alert(selectedButton)
    if (selectedButton = 'A1') {
      alert("You selected the first button!");
      location.replace();
    } else if (selectedButton = 'A2') {
      alert("You selected the second button!");
      location.replace();
    } else {
      alert("You selected the third button!");
      location.replace();
    }
}
```

Comment: for @SamsyTheUnicorn : in JS, C, and many languages `if (selectedButton='A1')` and `selectedButton = 'A1'` will alway do the same things : the variable `selectedButton` get the value `'A1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Assignment Operator `=`. You should use Comparison operator `==` or `===`. Better to use Strict Equality `===`

```
function choiceA(){
  alert(selectedButton)
    if (selectedButton === 'A1') {
      alert("You selected the first button!");
      location.replace();
    } else if (selectedButton === 'A2') {
      alert("You selected the second button!");
      location.replace();
    } else {
      alert("You selected the third button!");
      location.replace();
    }
}
```

You can make your code better and shorter by making an object.

```js
var selectedButton = 'A1';
function getRadioValue(param){
    selectedButton = param;
    console.log(selectedButton);
}

function choiceA(){
  const obj = {
    A1:'first',
    A2:'second'
  }
  alert(`You selected the ${obj[selectedButton] || 'third'} button`)
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A1')" value="A1" checked> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A2')" value="A2"> Proin volutpat eros fringilla felis euismod laoreet a eu velit. <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" onclick="getRadioValue('A3')" value="A3"> Mauris orci mi, luctus in leo eget, facilisis imperdiet lacus. <br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick=choiceA()> Choose </button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch case would be more fitting for the job. You also don't need to store the checked value. You can just query the checked element.

Although it will work with inline event handler on the button. I advice to use `addEventListener()` function in javascript to attach events.

```js
function choiceA() {
  var selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked').value;

  switch (selectedValue) {
    case "A1":
      console.log("A1 selected");
      break;
    case "A2":
      console.log("A2 selected");
      break;
    case "A3":
      console.log("A3 selected");
      break;
    default:
      //some error logging would be good incase you ever decide to add a 4th option and forget to update this function.
      console.log("Something went terribly wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="A1" checked> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="A2"> Proin volutpat eros fringilla felis euismod laoreet a eu velit. <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="A3"> Mauris orci mi, luctus in leo eget, facilisis imperdiet lacus. <br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick=choiceA()> Choose </button>
</form>
```